# Conditional Formatting with more than one variable

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, conditional-formatting

```
If ( cell A10 =2 ) AND ( cells C10:c15 through d10:d15 are blank)

Then color cells c10:15 through d10:15 red
```

I can do one or the other but can't figure out how to make it meet both criteria prior to coloring it red

Answer (score 0):

Try creating this new conditional formatting rule with `use formula to determine which cells to format` using the formula below which is only true if A10=2 and C10:C15 and D10:D15 are blank:

```
=AND(A10=2,COUNTBLANK(C10:C15)=6,COUNTBLANK(D10:D15)=6)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that should work also, thanks!  I was being overly cautious.